# SQL query to XML formating

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I am receiving the information I want. However, some of the elements have white space after the data such as First and Last name elements. I would like to remove this white space. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the code I'm working with. It pulls data from a db2 database using sql query.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'APP1' THEN 'Region1'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'APP2' THEN 'Region2'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'APP3' THEN 'Region3'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'App4' THEN 'Region4'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'App5' THEN 'Region5'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'APP6' THEN 'Region6'
    WHEN DSRV_APPL_ID = 'APP7' THEN 'Traveling'
    ELSE NULL
END AS "Group"
,XMLSERIALIZE (
    CONTENT XMLELEMENT(
        NAME "Users",
        XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT(
                NAME "User",
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "USERID", DSRQ_SUBJ_USERID),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "FIRST", DSAC_INDIV_FIRST),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "LAST", DSAC_INDIV_LAST),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "DSQ",  DSRQ_DSR_NUMBER),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "SEQ", DSRQ_SEQ_NUMBER),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "REQUESTOR", DSRQ_REQUESTOR_ID),
                    XMLELEMENT (NAME "STATUS", DSRQ_CURR_STATUS),
            )
            ORDER BY DSRV_APPL_ID
        )
    )
    AS CLOB (30K)
) AS "USERLIST"

FROM DB2PROD.REQUEST
    ,DB2PROD.SECUREAPRV
    ,DB2PROD.ACCESSTABLE

WHERE (DSRQ_STATUS_DATE > CURRENT DATE - 2 DAYS or
        DSRQ_OPEN_DATE > CURRENT DATE - 2 DAYS or
        DSRQ_CLOSED_DATE > CURRENT DATE - 2 DAYS)
    AND DSRQ_TYPE = 'A'
    AND DSRQ_SUB_TYPE IN ('A','C')
    AND DSRV_ADD_DELETE = 'A'
    AND DSRQ_SUBJ_USERID <> '        '
    AND DSRQ_CURR_STATUS IN ('OPEN')
    AND DSAC_EMPLOYEE_FLAG = 'Y'

    AND DSAC_INDIV_NAME <> ''
    AND DSRQ_DSR_NUMBER = DSAC_DSR_NUMBER
    AND DSRQ_SEQ_NUMBER = DSAC_SEQ_NUMBER

    AND DSRQ_DSR_NUMBER = DSRV_DSR_NUMBER
    AND DSRQ_SEQ_NUMBER = DSRV_SEQ_NUMBER
    AND (DSRV_APPL_ID LIKE 'APP%')

GROUP BY DSRV_APPL_ID;

With UR
```

The data should output as an xml in the following format:

```
<Users>
    <USER>
        <UserID>ID1</UserID>
        <First>FirstName</First>
        <Last>LastName</Last>
        <DSQ>Ticket</DSQ>
        <SEQ>Sequence</SEQ>
        <REQUESTOR>Requestor ID</REQUESTOR>
        <STATUS>Current Status</STATUS>
    </USER>
    <USER>
        <UserID>ID2</UserID>
        <First>FirstName</First>
        <Last>LastName</Last>
        <DSQ>Ticket</DSQ>
        <SEQ>Sequence</SEQ>
        <REQUESTOR>Requestor ID</REQUESTOR>
        <STATUS>Current Status</STATUS>
    </USER>
<Users>
```

Instead the data looks like this:

```
<Users>
    <USER>
        <UserID>ID1</UserID>
        <First>FirstName                    </First>
        <Last>LastName                 </Last>
        <DSQ>Ticket</DSQ>
        <SEQ>Sequence</SEQ>
        <REQUESTOR>Requestor ID</REQUESTOR>
        <STATUS>Current Status</STATUS>
    </USER>
    <USER>
        <UserID>ID2</UserID>
        <First>FirstName               </First>
        <Last>LastName                 </Last>
        <DSQ>Ticket</DSQ>
        <SEQ>Sequence</SEQ>
        <REQUESTOR>Requestor ID</REQUESTOR>
        <STATUS>Current Status</STATUS>
    </USER>
<Users>
```

Comment: can you post the whole query, not sure where you get that data from but have you tried you use an ltrim and rtrim when you pull your data, Like a cte and then the xml logic. not sure if this helps since your tags dont tell much informatio what kinda sql you are using.

Comment: I'm using a Dell product to pull data from an IBM mainframe using SQL language. I have updated the question with the full query.

Comment: Also, how would I use rtrim? I'm not entirely familiar with SQL or XML. I've pieced this together through trial and error.

Comment: Maybe [trim with trailing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023198.html)?  Or maybe [strip](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_strip.html)?  Yeah well, some things in SQL aren't quite ansi standard in every DBMS.

Comment: I tried to use it as indicated in the document but it throws an error when I add those commands. Maybe I’m not using them right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you would need to remove trailing spaces from the columns where you don't want them, as the following fragment shows:

```
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "FIRST", RTRIM(DSAC_INDIV_FIRST)),
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "LAST", RTRIM(DSAC_INDIV_LAST)),
```

If the values have also leading spaces, wrap that in `LTRIM()` as well, or use the `TRIM()` function if it is available in your version of Db2 (you'll need to consult the manual for the specific version that you have).